# Java SDK QuickBooks Online. Direct HTTP — ok, SDK — auth fail

Tags: java, oauth, sdk, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Java project (Eclipse). Sandbox test app. I got all necessary token and secret pairs using the Sample OAuth app and assigned them to String variables: consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, appToken, companyID.

Next. I tried to authorize QBO in two different ways: directly with HTTP connection (try/catch blocks removed):

```
OAuthConsumer ouathconsumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(consumerKey,consumerSecret);

ouathconsumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

URL url = new URL("https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/" + companyID + "/customer/4");

urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Close");

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

ouathconsumer.sign(urlConnection);

urlConnection.connect();

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

System.out.println(rd.readLine());

rd.close();
```

And it works well! But I wanna do the SDK calls. Following source gives me error (try/catch removed, secret strings are the same):

```
IAuthorizer authorizer = new OAuthAuthorizer(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);

Context context = new Context(authorizer, appToken, ServiceType.QBO, companyID);

DataService service = new DataService(context);

Customer customer=new Customer();

customer.setId("3");

Customer resultCustomer = service.findById(customer);
```

Last line gives current error (some strings replaced by stars):

```
com.intuit.ipp.exception.AuthenticationException: ERROR CODE:3200, ERROR MESSAGE:message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401, ERROR DETAIL:SignatureBaseString: GET&https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com%2Fv3%2Fcompany%***%2Fcustomer%2F3&minorversion%3D3%26oauth_consumer_key%***%26oauth_nonce%3D-4488452729022111661%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1450088662%26oauth_token%***%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26requestid%3Dc5bba96ea6894dc3be93588324778891

at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.HandleResponseInterceptor.execute(HandleResponseInterceptor.java:91)

at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.IntuitInterceptorProvider.executeResponseInterceptors(IntuitInterceptorProvider.java:94)

at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.IntuitInterceptorProvider.executeInterceptors(IntuitInterceptorProvider.java:67)

at com.intuit.ipp.services.DataService.executeInterceptors(DataService.java:126)

at com.intuit.ipp.services.DataService.findById(DataService.java:215)

at test_qb.Start_QB.main(Start_QB.java:76)
```

It says something about auth error, but tokens are ok. Please help me out. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. NO SLASH MIGHT BE IN THE ENDING OF URL IN CONFIG!

also use logging tools provided by SDK & log4j

Comment: Hi I'm started working on quickbooks Sample CRUD Operations, but I'm getting one exception.